# Emoji's are replaced by '?' when parsing a whatsapp chat text file. How can I parse them as their normal UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: java, unicode, printing

I'm writing a little Java project for fun where I want to get statistics for whatsapp chats. In this case i want to get the emojis that are used most frequently as one of those statistics.

These chats look like this and are a regular txt file:

> 29-04-2021 18:49 - Friend_A: I’m also up for the party
> 29-04-2021 18:50 - Friend_B: I am also down
>
>  29-04-2021 18:52 - Friend_C: Im also down to party
> 29-04-2021 18:52 - Friend_A:
> Hahahahahaha
>  29-04-2021 18:52 - Friend_A: Okay I’ll do it 
> 29-04-2021 18:52 - Friend_D: I'll see how it goes ♡♡♡
>  29-04-2021
> 18:52 - Friend_E: Now I feel bad

I use this code to parse the text file

```
try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, when i use this code all the emoji's get replaced by either a single question mark ('?') or two question marks ('??'). I've done this before in python and had no issues.

Ive tried to set the encoding of the printstream to UTF-8 like this

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

using an InputStreamReader like below has the same results.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(filePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I feel like i'm missing something really simple here but i can't figure it out.

Comment: First, determine whether the problem is that you don't have the right font, or your code is buggy.  You cannot distinguish these cases just by seeing the wrong characters output.  Secondly, determine the encoding of the print stream. This may or may not be UTF-8.  You'd have to look at the raw hex to be able to see whether it is.

Comment: This may be a problem with System.out, not with your reader.

Comment: Or even with the underlying terminal, if it doesn't support (or is not configure to accept) Unicode output.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised, even if your terminal is Unicode-enabled, if it were using a font with the 'Unicode Character 'FACE WITH PARTY HORN AND PARTY HAT' (U+1F973)' glyph ;)

Comment: @iggy I've tried to set the encoding of the printstream to UTF-8 which caused other characters such as the apostrophe to now also get messed up. I've editted the post to show how i did that.
Im using a standard .txt file, is it even possible to have different fonts in .txt files?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using the standard Intellij terminal for output streams. I've used emoji's in Pycharm aswell without a problem which is a similar IDE by the same developers. How would i be able to check the encoding it uses?